# SQL select rows having continuous similar values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named "Students" with fields like...

```
Student          Code1      Code2      Code3      Code4

Mark             0           1         1          1        1
Joseph           0           1         0          1        0
Bryan.           0           0         1          1        1
```

So, the SQL query should select student having more than or equal to two 1's and that too they should be continuous..
In the above case .. Should return Mark and Bryan but not Joseph

Comment: Unfortunately, this schema is broken and you are up against a wall due to the design.

Comment: This is a horrible database design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only a handful of columns:

```
Select *
From Students
Where ( Code1 + Code2 ) = 2
    Or ( Code2 + Code3 ) = 2
    Or ( Code3 + Code4 ) = 2
    Or ( Code4 + Code5 ) = 2
```

Another solution:

```
With NormalizedData As
    (
    Select Student, Code1, 1 As Sequence From Students Where Code1 = 1
    Union All Select Student, Code2, 2 From Students Where Code2 = 1
    Union All Select Student, Code3, 3 From Students Where Code3 = 1
    Union All Select Student, Code4, 4 From Students Where Code4 = 1
    Union All Select Student, Code5, 5 From Students Where Code5 = 1
    )
Select ...
From Students As S
Where Exists    (
                Select 1
                From NormalizedData As N1
                    Join NormalizedData As N2
                        On N2.Student = N1.Student
                            And N2.Sequence = N1.Sequence + 1
                Where N1.Student = S.Student
                )
```

Comment: So ... write out a really long union instead of just use an UNPIVOT?

Comment: @KyleHale - IMO, it's a push. You are quibbling over adding a value to an In function or a Copy+Paste. Both solutions are lipstick on the pig of a data schema which doesn't fit the business problem.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it

```sql
SELECT Student
FROM 
(
  SELECT Student,(CONVERT(CHAR(1),Code1) + 
                  CONVERT(CHAR(1),Code2) + 
                  CONVERT(CHAR(1),Code3) + 
                  CONVERT(CHAR(1),Code4)) AS Codes
  FROM Students
) s1
WHERE CHARINDEX('11', Codes) > 0
```

Here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e6e87/45)

Comment: Why the `OR CHARINDEX('00', Codes) > 0` clause?

Comment: Fair point. Misread OP's question. Thought it should be two or more consecutive values (ones OR zeros). Updated the answer. Thanks for paying attention.

Answer (score 0):

While it is true your schema is very, very strange, you can solve it pretty trivially with an UNPIVOT, assuming you're on SQL Server 2005 or greater. Note you have to supply a hardcoded list of all of your codes to the unpivot ...

```
WITH pvt (student, code, value) as (
        SELECT 
            Student,
            ROW_NUMBER()OVER(Partition By Student Order By Codes) as CodeId, 
            Value
        FROM 
            ( select * from students ) P
        UNPIVOT ( 
            Value FOR Codes IN (Code1, Code2, Code3, Code4, Code5) 
        ) Code
    )

    select 
    distinct
        pvt.student
    from 
        pvt
        inner join pvt p2
            on p2.code = pvt.code + 1
            and p2.student = pvt.student
    where 
        pvt.value = 1 and p2.value = 1
```

The real advantage here is you only have to deal with your various codes in one place - if you add Code6 for example you just add it to the UNPIVOT and it'll be incorporated into the code.

Also note this just solves for the more general requirement of "student must have 2 continuous 1s in the codes." It doesn't check to see how many 1s the student has, or care where the 2 values fall.

And the last caveat is that the ROW_NUMBER() function is assuming that your codes are sequentially named with no gaps, so if you go from Code7 to Code9 it'll just assume those two are "continuous."